# How to remove xml nodes without attribute in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-delete

What is the correct way to remove all child nodes of the root node with a missing attribute from an xml field in Sql Server 2008?

My Xml looks like this, I want to remove all the child nodes of `<root>` that don't have the `ln` attribute specified

```
<root>
  <title />
  <title />
  <questionphrase ln="nl">
    <xhtml />
  </questionphrase>
  <questionphrase ln="en">
    <xhtml />
  </questionphrase>
  <information ln="nl">
    <xhtml />
  </information>
  <information ln="en">
    <xhtml />
  </information>
  <title />
  <title ln="en">
     value
  </title>
  <label ln="en">
     value
  </label>
  <title />
  <title />
</root>
```

After the delete the xml should look like this

```
<root>
  <questionphrase ln="nl">
    <xhtml />
  </questionphrase>
  <questionphrase ln="en">
    <xhtml />
  </questionphrase>
  <information ln="nl">
    <xhtml />
  </information>
  <information ln="en">
    <xhtml />
  </information>
  <title ln="en">
     value
  </title>
  <label ln="en">
     value
  </label>
</root>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to permanently remove them in the table, or just hide them during a `SELECT`?

Comment: I want to completely remove them, it's corrupt data that only causes overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '....'
SET @xml.modify('delete //root/*[not(@ln)]')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8210)**